# How to italicize within \{itemize}

Tags: itemize, italic

I am trying to italicize within itemize.

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item \textit{test}
\end{itemize}
```

The italicization isn't working within the context of the overleaf template that I am working off of ([link](https://overleaf.com/project/6147f2eb92ff46316a68748c)).

Comment: works fine -- u can also use `\emph` instead of `\textit` -- maybe something else in your not shown code is interfering

Comment: Yes, it's not working in the context of the template that I'm working in. This is the template I'm basing my CV on: https://www.overleaf.com/project/6147f2eb92ff46316a68748c

Comment: that link does not work

Comment: Sorry, try this one: https://www.overleaf.com/1837913949qwmjxfggrcgt

Comment: You should provide MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small but complete document) which reproduce your problem.

Comment: what does "not working mean"? You have not provided any code we can run to see the problem, nor shown any error message or described any wrong output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template uses a font that has different names for all the styles. This means `fontspec` cannot automatically find the variants such as bold or italics, and you need to specify these manually.

The easiest way is to (re)set the main font from within your own document with an explicit italics font name:

```
\setmainfont[Color=primary, ItalicFont=Lato-LigIta, Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}
```

Then use `\textit` as normal:

```
\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}

\setmainfont[Color=primary, ItalicFont=Lato-LigIta, Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}

\begin{document}

% [...]

\begin{tightemize}
\item Specialization in \textit{Industrial Management}
\end{tightemize}
```

Result:

[image]

There are various italics fonts to choose from with different weights, like `Lato-RegIta`, `Lato-BolIta` etc., located in the `/fonts` folder of the template. Above I picked `LigIta` which is the lightest variant, to match the main font `Lato-Lig`.

Note also that the color name `primary` is defined by the template, when using this approach in different contexts the color setting can be removed or adjusted to a predefined or other custom defined color name.

Comment: @Marjin Thank you so much! More generally, I'm seeing errors like this in my console (due to other fonting issues). What is your method for extrapolating the necessary tag from the error? ```LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/Lato-Lig(2)/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/Lato-Lig(2)/m/n' instead on input line 21.```

Comment: Those warnings are about the smallcaps (sc) variant of the Lato font - even though smallcaps seem to be part of the font it doesn't seem to have a proper NFSS spec (see the log file from about halfway down). If you're ok with not using smallcaps then you can just ignore that warning. Note that the Raleway font (which is used for the `\descript` macro among other things) does have a proper smallcaps variant which is shown in the CV (for example in 'Heraklion, Greece').